# Install4j upgrade installation sometimes gives "Error opening media file. Please move this file to an ascii-only path like c:\"

Tags: install4j

...and then:
"Log: C:\Users\GEBRUIKER2\AppData\Local\Temp\i4j_nlog_7"

This happens consistently, but on relatively few machines only (ca. 1 in 100), and only when trying to update an existing installation. It happens both for install4j 5.1.15 and 6.1.2.

The only reliable work-around is to uninstall and reinstall manually, which means we have to contact all affected customers to do this for them.

I found this related link:
https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=31405

However, they "solved" it by doing the manual uninstall-reinstall cycle, which does not scale for many customers.

What causes this error - the listed file is clearly on an ASCII-only path already - and what can we do to solve it in general?

Comment: Can you find out on what path the installer is located in such a case?

Comment: The i4j_nlog_5 file contains the following:
`Started executable C:\Users\Guest46\CareConnect-ACC_windows-x64_2.7.17318.exe at Fri Aug 19 14:42:32 2016

ERROR: Could not open`

Comment: Apparently, the error happens when immediately clicking "install now" as soon as the update has been marked as downloaded in the updater. Waiting for a split second prevents the error. Could be a race condition, where the download has not yet been placed in the download folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment on the question:

> Apparently, the error happens when immediately clicking "install now" as soon as the update has been marked as downloaded in the updater. Waiting for a split second prevents the error.

This sounds like an Anti-Virus-Tool is checking the downloaded executable and is preventing read access to it.

In your updater, look for the action named "Download URL" and add a "Sleep" action right after it.